# how do I know whether I am currently in chained or unchained mode

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase, sybase-ase-15.7

In Sybase server-side language how can my code test whether it's running in chained or unchained (auto-commit) mode?

Examining the status of `@@TRANCOUNT` is not really conclusive.

I gather that there must be a way as for instance, JDBC provides [getAutoCommit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getAutoCommit()) which is able to detect whether the connection is in auto-commit (unchained) mode or not. But how do I do that from within a stored procedure?

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2919018/274677) but it seems to answer for SQL Server only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase ASE's default mode is unchained, as I suspect you already know.

You can use `SELECT @@tranchained;` to see the status for the current session's transaction chaining mode.

The result is either 0 or 1, per the following:

```
0 = unchained
1 = chained
```

Transaction chaining mode can be modified with `SET CHAINED ON;` or `SET CHAINED OFF;`